# How to specify command attribute in h:inputText?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a function that I derclare beans in my manager and I want to return the value in inputText but when I put the name of my function in the value attribute of inputText tag like this:

```
<p: inputText value = "#{ticketBean.getLastIndexTache} "/>
```

this error appear:

```
Etat HTTP 500 - /pages/test.xhtml @13,106 value="#{ticketBean.getLastIndexTache}": Property 'getLastIndexTache' not found on type com.bean.TicketBean
```

here is the java code

```
@ManagedBean(name="ticketBean") 
public class TicketBean {
public int getLastIndexTache() {
        Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
            int index = 0;
            try {
                session.beginTransaction();
                String sql = "select MAX(t.IDTICKET) from ticket t ";
                Query query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
                if( query.uniqueResult()==null){

                    index=0;
                }else{

                    index=(int) query.uniqueResult();
                    index=index+1;
                }
            } catch (HibernateException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                session.getTransaction().rollback();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
                return index;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the bean property in `value` like

```
<p:inputText value="#{ticketBean.lastIndexTache}"/>
```

as JSF by itself adds "get" to the property name. Currently it will look for the method `getGetLastIndexTache()`.

Besides its very bad practice to have logic in any getter as they are called multiple times by JSF. Instead you should make an property like

```
private Integer lastIndexTache; // +getter/setter
```

and set the value in a @PostConstruct method:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    Session session =  HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    // etc....
    lastIndexTache = index;
 }
```

The getter would then simply be

```
public Integer getLastIndexTache() {
    return lastIndexTache;
}
```

and don't forget a setter:

```
public void setLastIndexTache(Integer newValue) {
   lastIndexTache = newValue;
}
```

Also you should probably put a scope on the bean (for example @ViewScoped).

Comment: I add all the changes but still the same problem :(

Comment: Try restarting server and remember the ViewScoped-annotation must be from the correct package

Comment: I added the annotation view Scope in the  header of my class manager

Comment: And it still doesent work after rebuild? Could you post the error, I cant see how it can be the same error? Do you use javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped (from this package)?

Comment: For detail on "bad practice", see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times/